# adding forward slash after rewrite if not exist

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have read a ton and tried a ton of solutions, but can't find one specific to my needs.

In my htaccess I have the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^profile/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1&type=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^profile/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1&type=$2&o=$3 [L,QSA]
```

This works wonderfully, except for 1 small problem.

If `profile/username` does not have a `/` the links on the page will break unless absolute urls are used. So `<a href="./1">` will end up as `profile/1` instead of `profile/username/1`

If I change the first rewrite to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([\w-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

then `https://myurl/username` will return a 404 which I do not want - I want it to force the / on the end if it does not exist.

I have tried adding:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

I have tried

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://nmyurl/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Just can't figure out how to do this with the rewrite conditions already in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So unfortunately I wasn't able to actually achieve what I was hoping to because there are multiple levels of variables that may or may not exist.

In part I used the solution provided by Amit:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/profile/
RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R]
```

However this wasn't enough, because as pointed out by MrWhite there are 3 separate potential url's.

```
https://myurl/profile/username/
https://myurl/profile/username/type/
https://myurl/profile/username/type/o/
```

In this sitation username should always exist, but type and o may or may not exist.

So what I did was detect the level of the url and then created conditional . and .. using php.

The variable o is always numeric and variable type is never numeric so this worked for me.

```
if (isset($_GET['o'])) { $o = strip_tags($_GET['o']); }
elseif (isset($_GET['type']) && is_numeric($_GET['type'])) { $o = strip_tags($_GET['type']); }
```

Then I detect:

```
// if o is set or if type is numberic, use ..
if (isset($_GET['o']) || (isset($_GET['type']) && is_numeric($_GET['type']))) {
  $dots = '..';
// if o is not set and type is not numeric just use .
} else {
  $dots = '.';
}
```

end result of `<a href="'.$dots.'/1/">1</a>`:

```
if url is https://myurl/profile/username/
result is https://myurl/profile/username/1/

if url is https://myurl/profile/username/3/
result is https://myurl/profile/username/1/

if url is https://myurl/profile/username/type/3/
result is https://myurl/profile/username/type/1/
```

Which was the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

To add an optional traling at the end of your `profile` URLs you can use this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/profile/
RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R]
```

Comment: there should be a / after profile `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/profile/` otherwise it will redirect to `profile.php/?username=username`

Comment: @Bruce Yes, you are right. I have updated the code with your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> If `profile/username` does not have a `/` the links on the page will break unless absolute urls are used. So `<a href="./1">` will end up as `profile/1` instead of `profile/username/1`

If the issue only applies to URLs of the form `/profile/<username>` then I would be specific and only append the trailing slash to these specific URLs, otherwise, you are going to get a lot of redirects (which could be detrimental to SEO).

However, you should ensure that internal links are for the canonical URL (ie. with the trailing slash).

For example, the following should go *before* your existing rewrites:

```
RewriteRule ^(profile/[\w-]+)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Since the canonical URL requires a trailing slash this should be a 301 (permanent) redirect. (But test with a 302 first.)

---

Alternatively, instead of redirecting in `.htaccess` (if you are still linking to the slashless URL internally) then you could add a `base` element (that includes the trailing slash) to the `head` section to state what relative URLs should be relative to.

For example:

```
<base href="/profile/<username>/">
```

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^profile/([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
> RewriteRule ^profile/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1&type=$2 [L,QSA]
> RewriteRule ^profile/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1&type=$2&o=$3 [L,QSA]
> ```

The two `RewriteCond` directives would seem to be entirely superfluous. `RewriteCond` directives only apply to the first `RewriteRule` that follows. But the `RewriteRule` *patterns* are unlikely to match real files anyway (unless you have files without extensions or directories with the same name).

Comment: The rewrites work perfectly for my intent. the first one allows `/profile/username/` which is actually `profile.php?username=username`. The second one allow `/profile/username/type/` which is actually `profile.php?username=username&type=type`. The third allows `/profile/username/type/12/` which is actually `profile.php?username=username&type=type&o=12`. I then use php inside profile.php to get `if(isset($_GET['username'])) {}` and `if(isset($_GET['type'])) {}` and `if(isset($_GET['o'])) {}` to get the variables.

Comment: @Bruce Yes, I can see what those directives do - they are not in question. With regards to your existing rewrites, I was just saying that the two `RewriteCond` directives are superfluous and should be removed (they are performing 2 unnecessary filesystem checks). In order to "force the `/` on the end" of that specific URL, you need a redirect as I've mentioned above. Is this working for you? The redirect must go before your existing rewrites.

Comment: I pieced together a solution of my own and added it using both of the answers provided. :)

Comment: I see what you meant, yeah its just a force of habit to prevent conflicts in case at some point directories have same name as files - however unlikely as that may be.